# wxPython method Freeze turns widget black

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, gtk3, freeze-thaw

Centos 7.4,
Python 3.6.8,
wxPython 4.1.0

```
import wx
app = wx.App()
myFrame = wx.Frame(None, title="")
myPanel = wx.Panel(myFrame)
myStaticText = wx.StaticText(myPanel, label="Hello World")
mySizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
mySizer.Add(myStaticText, wx.SizerFlags().Center())
myPanel.SetSizer(mySizer)
myFrame.Show()
#myFrame.Freeze()
app.MainLoop()
```

While running the above code, a widget appears with the text "Hello World" visible. However, if the code is run with the commented line uncommented, a completely black widget will be displayed. Why does this Freeze call change the widget display? Freeze is supposed to prevent any updates to the widget display.

Dependencies: gtk3-devel, libXtst-devel, libtiff-devel, gcc gcc-c++ epel-release, libGLU-devel

Comment: I don't see a call to `myFrame.Thaw()`.

Comment: This is the simplest code I could make in order to show my issue, which is with the call to Freeze, not Thaw. In my full code, I have a call to thaw, which turns the black widget back to normal. But my issue is that the call to Freeze shouldn't turn my widget black in the first place.

Comment: why do you need to call it in the first place? As vadim pointed out, this is rarely required.

Comment: I use it in my full code in order to prevent the screen from updating while it is frozen. Until I want the screen to update, in which I call Thaw.

Comment: why are you calling `Freeze()` after `Show()`? You might try to do it the other way around...

Comment: Because I want to freeze a frame that is already shown. This worked previously with Centos7.4 and wxPython 3.0.0, but when I updated to Phoenix, the behavior changed.

Answer (score 0):

`Freeze()` is supposed to *temporarily* suppress updating the display while you're modifying the widget repeatedly, in order to avoid unnecessary intermediate refreshes and the resulting flicker, but the widget **must** be thawed to allow it to redraw properly eventually. Leaving it frozen will prevent it from being updated, just as you observe.

Normally you will rarely, if ever, need to use this method. It's an optimization and definitely not something you ever *have* to use.

Comment: I agree, Freeze shouldn't change the display until Thaw is called, but my point is that the call to Freeze is turning my widget black instead of just pausing the display where it's at. I would expect the widget to display "Hello World" still while the widget is frozen.

Comment: The point is that you can't leave a widget frozen, i.e. your expectation is just not how it works. Freezing means forbidding any repaint completely.

Comment: @VZ. The behavior in Windows is what you would expect though - the frame freezes as-is. It does not turn black. Same with Python 2.7 + wxpython 3.0.0 + gtk2 in CentOS 7.4. The behavior of turning black on freeze only happens in CentOS + Python 3.6.8 + gtk3 + wxpython Phoenix. It is a new behavior that is not expected or documented. I tested this myself.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to explain it any better. Freezing a window and not thawing is not supported and not supposed to be done. It doesn't mean that it's going to fail in the same way everywhere (or even fail at all), it just means that it's absolutely not guaranteed to work, for any definition of "work".